# Dagger2 generate multiple instances

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I'm using Dagge2 in my kotlin project with pom file. I worked with Dagger in my android projects and it worked fine. But somehow I don't understand why Dagger generating multiple instances of my every object in kotlin.

Below is my **Component**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [MeterCollectionModule::class])
interface AppComponent {    

fun meterCollection(): MeterCollection

}
```

And this is my **Module**

```
@Module(includes = [UtilModule::class])
class MeterCollectionModule {

@Singleton
@Provides
fun meterCollection() = MeterCollection()
}
```

That's how I'm building my **AppComponent**

```
 DaggerAppComponent
      .builder()
      .build()
      .inject(this)
```

I debug my code and see, every time I inject MeterCollection class it gives me new object.

Comment: Are you reusing the same `AppComponent` to retrieve your `MeterCollection`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@Singleton` annotation (as well as any other scope annotation) is taken into account only if you're reusing the same component. In other words, Dagger is not able to respect your `@Singleton` scope across different instances of the same component.

Hence, in order to inject the same `MeterCollection` instance, you should also reuse the same `DaggerAppComponent` instance (e.g., by putting it in an instance variable).

Comment: How do I use the same **DaggerAppComponent**  in different classes?

Comment: You have multiple options. For example, you can link it to the `Application` object, which is unique for your application, assign it to an `object`s field, pass it around where you need it.

Comment: That's a great point but this is only valid if I developing my app in **Android**. But my problem is I'm developing a **Java-based** app.

Comment: It really depends on your use case: if those classes are somehow connected (e.g., if they're created through a Factory - we're in Java, after all - you can keep the `Component` inside the Factory). If you need your component to be accessible from anywhere, consider using the singleton pattern or some kind of "application" object (your program will have 1 entry-point, you can consider that as your "application" object)

Answer (score 1):

`Singleton` and `Provider` annotations won't work with object which is created every time method is called. I'd refactor the class to:

```
@Module(includes = [UtilModule::class])
class MeterCollectionModule {

val myMeterConnection = MeterConnection()

@Singleton
@Provides
fun meterCollection(){
    return myMeterConnection
}
```

(which is identical solution to what @user2340612 proposed)